# Can't install or deinstall any Plugin in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to install a Plugin (`Kotlin`) in `Android Studio 2.0` on Windows 7.

Easy Peasy - I go to `Settings` `>` `Plugins` `>` `Install JetBrains plugin...` `>` `Kotlin` `>` Click on `Install` `>` Wait for the download to finish, click the `Restart` `>` Wait for `AS` to restart `>` Check if plugin was installed in `Plugins` `>` List of plugins **without** `Kotlin`.

I already tried this multiple times, I downloaded the `.zip` from the `Kotlin` Website, tried to use this to install with `Install plugin from disk...` with the same result.
I tried to manually restart `Android Studio` (Clicked `postpone` in the popup).

I also tried to uninstall a plugin which I don't need anymore, I clicked `uninstall`, restartet `Android Studio` and it was still in the list of plugins.

I started `Android Studio` with administrator rights, tried to install the plugin with the same result.

If I click `disable` on the mentioned installed (but unused) plugin, `restart`, and it was still disabled. (Checkbox unchecked)

Edit: A complete reinstall did not solve the problem, neither the upgrade to the `2.1 beta` version.

Comment: Try to reinstall android studio, and then install the plugin

Comment: Reinstalling did not solve the problem.

Comment: Where is Android Studio installed? You might also want to try this with a new test account to see if the problem is related to your current login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Android Studio 3.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have same case with android 2.3.3. just uninstall and install again Android Studio, it's work for me. i'm not sure, but maybe any some corrupt in android studio, but still can use it.